# How do I specify exactly what I need to fill in HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

In my app, I created a canvas using HTML Canvas and I want to be able to click the page to draw a circle filled in with a color, click another part of the page and have the circles automatically connected with a line.

I nearly have it working however when I try to fill my circles, it also fills in the space between the circles.

Here is what it looks like when I try to use `ctx.fill()`:

```js
let hasCircle = false;

document.addEventListener('click', onMouseMove);

const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// Create a circle on page click
document.getElementById('canvas').onclick = function(event) {
 
  ctx.arc(event.clientX - 10, event.clientY - 10, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill()
  
    if (!hasCircle) {
      hasCircle = true;
    }
}

// Connect circles with a line
function onMouseMove(event) {
    if (hasCircle) {
      ctx.lineTo(event.clientX - 10, event.clientY - 10);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function reset() {
    hasCircle = false;
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Is there a way to specify exactly what I would like to fill with color?

Comment: you can pass a `Path2D` object to fill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a better time having a separate function that fully redraws the canvas based on your state (i.e. the points you have).

```js
const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const points = [];

function redraw() {
  c.width = c.width; // clear canvas
  if (!points.length) return;
  // Fill points one by one
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  points.forEach(([x, y]) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  });

  // Begin new path for polygon
  ctx.beginPath();
  points.forEach(([x, y], i) => {
    if (i == 0) ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    else ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  });
  ctx.lineTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
  ctx.stroke();
}

document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  points.push([event.clientX - 10, event.clientY - 10]);
  redraw();
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is really helpful, it definitely seems better to separate the functions. I am just starting with HTML canvas so the code for a new path for the polygon looks a little foreign to me. Is there a way I can modify that so I only have one line traversing the points from start to finish as opposed to them still being connected to the first point?

Comment: Remove the last `ctx.lineTo()` that's outside the loop. I figured you wanted a closed polygon, but I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: Ahh! This is exactly what I was trying to do. I now see why my code wasn't working but you've also shown me how to improve it. Thank you!